# Express server not installing on my machine

Tags: node.js, express

Am trying to install express library on my machine but keep getting this error message.

```
C:\Users\SAMMY WHITE SNR\Desktop\test>npm i express@4.17.1
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...rectories":{"lib":"./'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SAMMY WHITE SNR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-04T06_40_13_375Z-debug.log
```

Comment: ```npm cache clean --force``` as administrator user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me, try

```
npm cache clean --force
npm i express@4.17.1
```

also, I recommend installing the current stable version with

```
npm i express
```

Comment: You're welcome, can you please mark my answer as correct?